How to Update Metadata for a Created Token on Solana?
I have a token on Solana with the following details:
Token Address: HQpbrzB5T9cYLVGKXP5612unhNCBRJCxY9eBUHAWDZCy
Mint Address: 9ZiXrkY3TwzxEhZPoPv8BaSbgRAevVTaWTeTPQjmcvaW
Owner Address: Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg
How can I update the metadata for this token? I’ve tried updating the metadata using metaplex and metaboss, but nothing seems to be working. It feels like I’m doing something wrong. Could someone guide me on how to properly update the metadata for this token?
my metadata:
{
    "name": "EasyGO",
    "symbol": "EGO",
    "description": "$EGO is a travel game cryptocurrency that rewards users for exploring and completing travel-based challenges. It merges adventure with blockchain for an interactive and rewarding experience.",
    "image": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmU2agFxLcVLPWG6tmCBPfkrSAyeffUHVRRtnojgYSARv3"
}

const { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, Transaction } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Metadata, UpdateMetadataArgs } = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');
const { sendAndConfirmTransaction } = require('@solana/web3.js');

async function updateMetadata() {
  const connection = new Connection('https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmPeCSSMFVfyn4pYzr7j6YLrJYQPLzUWqN6dRNbK1hBuks', 'confirmed');
  const payer = Keypair.generate();
  const tokenMintAddress = new PublicKey('9ZiXrkY3TwzxEhZPoPv8BaSbgRAevVTaWTeTPQjmcvaW');
  const newUri = 'https://example.com/your-new-metadata.json';

  const metadataPDA = await Metadata.getPDA(tokenMintAddress);
  const metadata = await Metadata.load(connection, metadataPDA);

  const updateMetadataInstruction = Metadata.updateMetadata(
    connection,
    payer.publicKey,
    metadataPDA,
    payer.publicKey,
    newUri,
    null
  );

  const transaction = new Transaction().add(updateMetadataInstruction);
  const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer]);
  console.log("Transaction successful with signature: ", signature);
}

updateMetadata().catch(err => console.error("Error updating metadata:", err));


The mpl-token-metadata package requires you to use umi.
First you need to set up the umi framework: https://developers.metaplex.com/umi/getting-started#connecting-to-an-rpc
Metaplex has the docs on how to update tokens here:
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
In general, if this is a one time thing there are websites out there that you can use so that no code is required. One of those would be https://sol-tools.io/token-tools/token-management

How i understand, at https://sol-tools.io/token-tools/token-management i cant edit metadata, but can burn & mint.
Im trying to understand how to make it on Solana, not one time action. I have few project what i want migrate coin from cronos and ethereum to solana. Thank you!
